# Efficient SQL stored procedure with joins and distinct

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join, distinct

I am trying to get an efficient way of doing the stored procedure below. This procedure is to display a count of cars that belong to businesses in a market for all categories.

I have the category table being the primary select, then I go into the cars table to count the cars and join  their businesses within the category and here is where it really gets inefficient  I then check the market/locations selected or if none selected all markets. Here it is.

```
Create PROC  [USP_CAT]
  @MKT int

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT *,
      (
        SELECT COUNT(CAR_ID)
        FROM CARS
        INNER JOIN BUSINESS ON CAR_BIZ=BIZ_ID
        JOIN BIZCATS ON BC_BIZ = BIZ_ID AND BC_CAT = CAT_ID 
        WHERE  BIZ_APPROVED = 1 AND BIZ_EXPIRES >= getDate()  AND 
        (
          SELECT COUNT(BLOC_MKT)
          FROM BIZLOCS
          WHERE BIZ_ID = BLOC_BIZ AND (BLOC_MKT = @MKT OR @MKT = -1)
        )>0
      ) AS CAT_CAR_COUNT
    FROM CATS
    WHERE CAT_HIDE = 0
    ORDER BY CAT_ORDER asc

END
```

Any suggestion to tidy this up is much appreciated.

Comment: You would get better results if you posted the DDL, some sample inserts...and youre desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think an EXISTS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) might help out.

```
Create PROC  [USP_CAT]
  @MKT int

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT *,
      (
        SELECT COUNT(CAR_ID)
        FROM CARS
        INNER JOIN BUSINESS ON CAR_BIZ=BIZ_ID
        JOIN BIZCATS ON BC_BIZ = BIZ_ID AND BC_CAT = CAT_ID 
        WHERE  BIZ_APPROVED = 1 AND BIZ_EXPIRES >= getDate()  AND EXISTS
        (
          SELECT BLOC_MKT
          FROM BIZLOCS
          WHERE BIZ_ID = BLOC_BIZ AND (BLOC_MKT = @MKT OR @MKT = -1)
        )
      ) AS CAT_CAR_COUNT
    FROM CATS
    WHERE CAT_HIDE = 0
    ORDER BY CAT_ORDER asc

END
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, this is indeed an improvement; I will go with it.  

Just a side note, this is not a big part of the project on a whole, so if it affects performance when we are done, I will go with a no count option and just display categories.